# How does this line of code delete all the branches in github?

Tags: bash, grep, cut

I am going to do a clean up task for our static repository where we automate branches to.
I know this command deleted every branch besides prod but I haven't been able to figure out what the commands mean. What is the cut command and what is the $b for? Can anyone help break this down for me?

```
for b in `git branch --all | cut -c18- | grep -v prod`; do echo $b;
done for b in `git branch --all | cut -c18- | grep -v prod`; do git push origin :$b $b; done
```

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be a git problem.

Comment: Yep. Clearly `bash` rather than `git`.

Comment: `$b` is the `b` in `for b`.

Comment: The second `for b` shouldn't be on the same line as `done`.

Comment: As noted by others your main issues are with `bash`. But you also have `git` issues, I think: `git push origin :$b $b` should probably be `git push origin :$b` if you just want to delete branch `$b`. Else you're sending several local refs to the same remote ref which will probably cause an error.

Comment: And note that using `cut -c18-` to extract branch names looks really weird and not robust at all. If you have local branches, for instance, this will leave you with partial branch names.

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal run for each command and flag this `man command | sed -n "/^\s*flag/,/^$/p"` in case of cut -c
`man cut | sed -n "/^\s*-c/,/^$/p"`

Comment: I think this should just be a comment that says "Read the man page"

Comment: @Barmar not, this will strip just text except one for the particular flag, so there is no need for reading manual searching through the entire man page.

Comment: Yeah, but if they don't understand what `cut` does, telling them to just read the documentation for a single flag won't help them.

Comment: This trick is useful for commands with lots of options like `find`, assuming you understand the basic behavior. But you can also just use the search facility in the pager.

Comment: Yes, I have it like an alias, but one must know what command already does to make use of it, as You above pointed out.